# Send data to new window in the form

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a basic form and i have an auto-complete field using JavaScript.
this is how i bind the field in the form :

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.AlgoName, new {id="tags"})
```

now i need to add to the form next to the Text Box field a "Details" button 
that open a new window 
and send the

> AlgoName

to the new window.

AlgoName is part of my model.
How do i do that? please help me.
Thanks!!!

Comment: `that open a new window` do you mean new page? or dialog(modal) window?

Comment: I mean a new page, i think to do so maybe with AJAX?

Comment: You can try to access it by `$("AlgoName").val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest example:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" name="AlgoName" id="tags" /> 
<a href="#" id="details">Details</a>
```

**Javascript** (using jQuery):

```
$('#details').click(function(){
    var algoname = $('#tags').val(); // get the value of tags input assuming it is a string
    var url = "/mycontroller/details/"+algoname; 
    window.open(url , 'window name', 'window settings');
    return false;
});
```

**mycontroller**

```
public ActionResult details(string algoname)
{
    // validate algoname
    // get info related to algoname
    return Content("Here are all details!");
}
```